# Local Notification userinfo not getting in launch options

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter, userinfo

I'm sending `LocalNotification` from my iOS app. All notifications are arriving successfully. I'm handling those notifications using notification `userInfo` which is receiving from `didReceive response` function and facing no issues when app is in either background or foreground state.

But when app is in terminated (close) state, as we know that will get that notification userInfo in `launchoptions` as `launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]` of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in `AppDelegate`. But here I'm not getting that `userInfo` in `launchOptions`.

Let me know, is there anything need to enable in project settings? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.

```
    extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }
    
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            completionHandler()
            //response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        }
    
    }
```

Also, in didFinishLaucnhingOptions

```
if let notificationData = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
        //notificationData
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you mentioned, I'm using `willPresent notification` and `didReceive response` methods and as we know they will get called when app is in foreground or background state. When app is in terminated state, we will get notification data in `didFinishLaucnhingOptions` as you said, but here I'm not getting that notification data in `launchOptions`. That's the issue.

Comment: Hi @Harsha, Did you find any solution of it. I am facing the same problem. I am clicking on a local notification when app is terminated, notification data is getting in `launchOptions` of `didFinishLaucnhingOptions` in AppDelegate but there is only local notification key in launch options which is throwing warning of deprecation. Can you please let me know how to resolve this? Thanks